# How to handle & symbol in XML input in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an update stored procedure which takes @XML as input parameter. The XML is as below:

```
 <Root>
  <data>
    <FriendlyName>abc</FriendlyName>
    <URL>http://abc.aspx?view=Approval&Business=XYZ</URL>
  </data>
</Root>
```

When the stored procedure is executed, it throws error

> XML parsing: line 5, character 141, semicolon expected

It is failing because of the `&` symbol, instead it expects `&amp;`. So, how to replace `&` with `&amp;` before the XML is parsed?

Comment: If you have an XML parameter, shouldn't it be up to the caller to make sure that it is, in fact, passing real XML rather than something that just looks like XML?

Comment: Indeed. If the software that generates this is getting this wrong, it probably gets lots of other things wrong too. Don't try to repair bad XML, fix the code that produces it.

Answer (score 2):

You really should fix this where the XML is created. What you have here is not valid XML.

In SQL Server you can use [replace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to replace the values.

```sql
declare @S varchar(500)
declare @XML xml

set @S = '
<Root>
  <data>
    <FriendlyName>abc</FriendlyName>
    <URL>http://abc.aspx?view=Approval&Business=XYZ</URL>
  </data>
</Root>'

set @XML = replace(@S, '&', '&amp;')

select @XML
```

Result:

```xml
<Root>
  <data>
    <FriendlyName>abc</FriendlyName>
    <URL>http://abc.aspx?view=Approval&amp;Business=XYZ</URL>
  </data>
</Root>
```